# Sending 'float' data over Socket

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, tcp

The client sends the name of file to the server. The server crawls the file system for all instances of the file and populates a dictionary with keys as absolute paths and values as sizes of files.

The code I have written seems to be logically correct but sometimes runs successfully and sometimes gives error.

Server

```
import socket;
import sys;
import os;

serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
host = socket.gethostname();
port = 49000;
serverSocket.bind((host, port));
serverSocket.listen(1);

while True:
  connectionSocket, address = serverSocket.accept();
  fileName = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode();

  dictionary = {};

  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(os.sep)):
    for f in files:
      if f == fileName:
        dictionary[os.path.join(path, f)] = os.stat(f).st_size / 1024;

  if len(dictionary) == 0:
    connectionSocket.send(('0').encode());
    print();
    print('File not found!');
    sys.exit();
  else:
    connectionSocket.send(('1').encode());

  connectionSocket.send(str(len(dictionary)).encode());
  for key, value in dictionary.items():
    connectionSocket.send(key.encode('utf-16'));
    # If i don't write following line, error vanishes
    connectionSocket.send(str(value).encode('utf-16'));

  # File transfer
  f = open(fileName, 'rb');
  byte = f.read(1024);
  while (byte):
    #print('Sending...');
    connectionSocket.send(byte);
    byte = f.read(1024);
  f.close();
  print();
  print('Done sending.');
  connectionSocket.close();
  break;
```

Client

```
import socket;
import sys;
import os;

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
  print();
  print('Invalid arguments!');
  sys.exit();

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
host = socket.gethostname();
port = 49000;
clientSocket.connect((host, port));
clientSocket.send((sys.argv[1]).encode());

if clientSocket.recv(1024).decode() == '0':
  print();
  print('File not found!');
  sys.exit();

dictionary_size = int(clientSocket.recv(1024).decode());
for i in range(dictionary_size):
  print();
  print(clientSocket.recv(1024).decode('utf-16'));
  # If I don't write this line, error vanishes
  print(float(clientSocket.recv(1024).decode('utf-16')));

# File Transfer
byte = clientSocket.recv(1024);
f = open('Received_' + sys.argv[1], 'wb');
while (byte):
  #print ('Receiving...');
  f.write(byte);
  byte = clientSocket.recv(1024);
f.close();
print();
print('Done receiving.');
clientSocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR);
clientSocket.close();
```

Comment: TCP is a stream. The first call of recv may or may not consume the complete data that the other party sent. The solution would probably include something like a start, stop and seperator value between the actual values. Your receiving code can then recv until the end symbol is received

Comment: When it doesn't work what is the error? Please provide the complete traceback if possible. Couple of comments: 1) Python isn't C/C++, so you don't need to terminate each statement with a `;`. 2) You're not sending the size of the file, the expression `os.stat(f).st_size / 1024` calculates only the whole number of 1K blocks, but truncation due to integer division doesn't account for any final partial block.

Comment: Whats the error that you see?

Comment: Error:

http://i.imgur.com/fW1FscL.png

Comment: @martineau You said
    os.stat(f).st_size / 1024
gives the whole number but when I print() it, it gives the correct size with floating value. I've recently begun using Python. ';' is old habit. Is it a bad practice?

Comment: In that case you must be using Python 3 (and should tag your question as such).